# How to make a Loader for WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, loader

i need a Loader application in C# that check if my program is crashed for any reason and restart it.

How can i do it?

I mean how can i do it spending less resource as possible?

I wouldnt do another loader that check my loader :)

Thanks

Edit: Ah i forgot that i would my application doesnt start without loader. Is it possible to do or should i make it as Optional?

Comment: i was thinking to do a winform with timer but it use useful resource, i think.

Comment: Have you written any code that we can see? Can you describe the issues you've encountered so far? Have you tried searching for an answer before posting here?

Comment: I made many research but i didnt understand if i can use Mutex or not with WinForm Application.Cause name could change and if i give that right name it doesnt work. But my question was a bit different i know. By the way Console application use less resource right? Cause i could use it instead a winform application to do the loader.

Comment: Seems to me that if your program has crashed, perhaps just restarting it is a bad idea. You'd be better off fixing the program so that it doesn't crash in the first place. That way you wouldn't risk losing data, and you wouldn't have to write another program to monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for sounds like a watchdog, and has very little to do with a loader.
Try [this Google Search](http://www.google.co.il/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=watchdog#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=watchdog%20C#&pbx=1&oq=watchdog%20C#&aq=f&aqi=g1g-b2g-vC1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=27344l28111l0l28554l3l3l0l0l0l0l273l712l2-3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e31d7b9b2d541da4&biw=1280&bih=709), and maybe even [this specific article](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/08/monitored-watchdog-asynchronous-process-in-c/).

Regarding your second question, if you want your application not to be executable by any means other then another program, why not make it a DLL and be done with it? You can even go the extra mile and use some identification mechanism to make sure that only your application can activate that DLL.
If it's important to compile it to an executable, then you can't really make it impossible to execute, but you can make it non-trivial by using a password-like mechanism.